# Python import from __init__.py file

Tags: python, import

I have a module with `__main__` file and `__init__` file in a package.

I want to import a function from the `__init__` file:

```
import <package name>
<package name>.run_main()
```

and it failed with:

```
ImportError: No module named <package name>
```

I tried to add:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

But it didn't help.

Does anyone have a idea how can I solve it?

Comment: `from . import run_main` should work.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way, currently supported by PEP8 is to make your **main** code as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

and of course, making the main a function with no arguments:

```
def main():
```

therefore, if you'd like to import that main function if could be as follows:

```
from <filename> import *
<filename>.main()
```